# Remove page headers without removing post headers

Tags: php, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Using WordPress. My header navigation includes pages that link to categories. For instance, the 'about' in the header navigation is a page but it links to a category called 'about'. On this page, I have the page title displaying and then the post with the 'about' category is also displayed on this page.

When I try to remove the page title ('About') it removes that title AND the post's title on that page.

Ex. I am able to modify the pages with: (`.category-21` is the ID for the about page)

```
.category-21,
.category-22,
.category-23 {
    color: blue;
}
```

But when I try to remove the page title with:

```
.category-21 h2,
.category-22 h2,
.category-23 h2 {
    display: none;
}
```

It removes the page title AND the post's title.

The problem is that the header 2 modifies both titles.

- How do I separate the two?
- What would I add/modify to `functions.php` (or `single.php`?) and to `style.css`?

I'm also using this to exclude posts with the category of 'about' (and two others):

```
function excludeCat($query) {
if ( $query->is_home ) {
$query->set('cat', '-21, -22, -23');
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'excludeCat');
```

I think it's also excluding these categories from certain style changes in `style.css` (if that helps).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add more code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
.category-23 h2:nth-child(2)
```

OR

```
.category-23 h2:last-child
```

OR

Add a class to another h2 and then change the style of it.